# c callbacks functions for numerical optimization

Tags: c, optimization, callback, scope, nested-function

My application library needs to call an optimization routine:

```
 err = optim(int n, double *x, double *f, void *obj)
```

The routine will then call the objective function to request objective function value.

```
 void obj(int n, double *x, double *f)
```

optim() is part of an external library. The signature for optim() and obj() are fixed.

The function `obj()` needs to access data contained in single object 'model'. All other functions pass around pointer to the model object. So, a call to run the optimizer may be like:

```
 err = doOptimize(model)
```

`doOptimize()` will set up the problem and call `optim()`

```
 err= optim(model->n, model->x, model->f, model->obj)
```

The question is, can the `obj()` function access variables that reside in the `model` object, besides `n`, `x`, and `f`? `obj()` function would need to call other functions that need the `model` object to do the actual computations:

```
    updateParms(model);
    computeF(model);
```

I am not sure how `obj()` could make these calls without the actual handle? Can the following work?

```
    updateParms();
    computeF();
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are you talking about data other than the `n`, `x` and `f` members ? Could you provide a more elaborate code sample, and indicate exactly what you're trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and no.

Your function `obj` can access the model just like any other memory, of course, but I don't see any mechanism for it to know the address of `model`.

You need to add another parameter to `obj` in which to pass the `model` pointer.

In C++, you would probably do this by making `obj` a "member" of `Class Model`. The compiler would then add a hidden parameter called `this` (it does it for a all member functions) which would contain the pointer to the object instance 'model'. If you want to achieve the same in plain C then you have to pass your own `this` pointer around (but you can call it whatever you like).

So, something like this:

```
... doOptimize (... model)
{
  ....
  optim (model->n, model->x, model->x, model)
  ....
}

... optim (int n, double *x, double *f, ... model)
{
  ....
  model->obj (n, x, f, model);
  ....
}

void obj (int n, double *x, double *f, ... model)
{
   /* use n, x, and f */
   /* use model->stuff */
}
```

Of course, if you *always* use the same `n`, `x` and `f` then you need only pass `model`.

BTW, don't use `void *` for function pointers: it's not a good idea.

Comment: Your solution describes the problem better than my description. optim() is part of an external library.  Signature for optim() and obj() are fixed.  The very fact that I am unable to formulate the problem as suggested motivates the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot modify the signatures of `optim()` or `obj()` you will need to create an intermediate step that performs the real call to your `obj()` function. Depending on how many optimisation calls need to be made at once this could be as simple as a global/static variable that holds the model pointer, e.g.:

```
void obj(struct model *m, int n, double *x, double *f)
{
    /* Access to all information here */
}

static struct model *optim_model;

void obj_caller(int n, double *x, double *f)
{
    obj(optim_model, n, x, f);
}

int doOptimize(struct model *m)
{
    optim_model = m;
    return optim(m->n, m->x, m->f, obj_caller);
}
```

Or if you need to be more advanced or dislike having a single global and it's possible to use the n parameter as an identifier which you use to break out to be able to call multiple optimisation models:

```
void obj(struct model *m, int n, double *x, double *f)
{
    /* Access to all information here */
}

#define MAX_MODELS (10)
static struct model *optim_models[MAX_MODELS] = {0};

void obj_caller(int n, double *x, double *f)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MODELS; i++)
    {
        if (optim_models[i]->n == n)
        {
            obj(optim_models[i], n, x, f);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int doOptimize(struct model *m)
{
    return optim(m->n, m->x, m->f, obj_caller);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct model m1;
    struct model m2;

    m1.n = 1;
    optim_models[0] = &m1;

    m2.n = 2;
    optim_models[1] = &m1;

    int err = doOptimize(&m2);
}
```

I'm sure you coule find a more suitable method for storing multiple models if you need to, such as a linked list with real identifiers.